# Entity Framework Exception: Index was outside of the bounds of the array."

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, ado.net

OK, I am having and issue with Entity Framework. I have had it working, but have now added several more entities to the model, and now I am getting the above error. For debugging purposes, I have created a test form with a grid control to populate from my Projects entity collection. FYI, I am using GUID's for my primary keys. I only have one bit of code:

```
Public Class TestForm
Private Sub TestForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.ProjectBindingSource.DataSource = My.Application.Context.Projects
End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the Exception detail:

Inner Exception: {"Index was outside the bounds of the array."}
Source: "System.Data.Entity"

> System.Data.EntityCommandCompilationException was unhandled
>     Message="An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details."
>     Source="System.Data.Entity"
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree)
>          at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree)
>          at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
>          at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree)
>          at System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Span span)
>          at System.Data.Objects.EntitySqlQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>          at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>          at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetIListSourceListInternal()
>          at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery.System.ComponentModel.IListSource.GetList()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ListBindingHelper.GetList(Object list)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ListBindingHelper.GetList(Object dataSource, String dataMember)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.ResetList()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.set_DataSource(Object value)
>          at TestApp.TestForm.TestForm_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\JoshPeltier.TFEARTH\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\Forms\TestForm.vb:line 3
>          at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
>          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
>          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
>          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
>          at TestApp.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>     InnerException: System.IndexOutOfRangeException
>          Message="Index was outside the bounds of the array."
>          Source="System.Data.Entity"
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.CellQuery.CreateFieldAlignedCellQueries(CellQuery otherQuery, MemberPathMapBase projectedSlotMap, CellQuery& newMainQuery, CellQuery& newOtherQuery)
>               at System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.CellNormalizer.AlignFields(IEnumerable`1 cells, MemberPathMapBase projectedSlotMap, ViewTarget viewTarget)
>               at System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.CellNormalizer.CreateLeftCellWrappers(IEnumerable`1 extentCells, ViewTarget viewTarget)
>               at System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.CellNormalizer..ctor(EntitySetBase extent, IEnumerable`1 extentCells, SchemaContext schemaContext, CqlIdentifiers identifiers, ConfigViewGenerator config, MemberDomainMap queryDomainMap, MemberDomainMap updateDomainMap, StorageEntityContainerMapping entityContainerMapping, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
>               at System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewGenerator.GetCellNormalizer(EntitySetBase extent, SchemaContext schemaContext, CqlIdentifiers identifiers)
>               at System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewGenerator.GenerateViewsForExtent(SchemaContext schemaContext, EntitySetBase extent, CqlIdentifiers identifiers, KeyToListMap`2 views)
>               at System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewGenerator.GenerateViewsForSchemaContext(SchemaContext schemaContext, CqlIdentifiers identifiers, KeyToListMap`2 views)
>               at System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewGenerator.GenerateAllViews(KeyToListMap`2 views, CqlIdentifiers identifiers)
>               at System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewGenerator.GenerateViewsForSchemaCells(List`1 cells, MetadataWorkspace workSpace, ConfigViewGenerator config, CqlIdentifiers identifiers, StorageEntityContainerMapping containerMapping)
>               at System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewGenerator.GenerateViewsForSchema(StorageEntityContainerMapping containerMapping, MetadataWorkspace workSpace, ConfigViewGenerator config)
>               at System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.SerializedGenerateViews(EntityContainer container, Dictionary`2 resultDictionary)
>               at System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.SerializedGetGeneratedViews(EntityContainer container)
>               at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Evaluate>b__0()
>               at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()
>               at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)
>               at System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.GetGeneratedView(EntitySetBase extent, MetadataWorkspace workspace, StorageMappingItemCollection storageMappingItemCollection)
>               at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetGeneratedView(EntitySetBase extent)
>               at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ExpandView(Node node, ScanTableOp scanTableOp, IsOfOp& typeFilter)
>               at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ProcessScanTable(Node scanTableNode, ScanTableOp scanTableOp, IsOfOp& typeFilter)
>               at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ScanTableOp op, Node n)
>               at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ScanTableOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
>               at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
>               at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.VisitChildren(Node n)
>               at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
>               at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ProjectOp op, Node n)
>               at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
>               at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
>               at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.VisitChildren(Node n)
>               at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n)
>               at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitPhysicalOpDefault(PhysicalOp op, Node n)
>               at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.Visit(PhysicalProjectOp op, Node n)
>               at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.PhysicalProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
>               at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
>               at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Process()
>               at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Process(PlanCompiler planCompilerState, StructuredTypeInfo& typeInfo)
>               at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets)
>               at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(DbCommandTree ctree, List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets)
>               at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree)
>          InnerException:

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error. I've been using this model for quite a while with no errors but after doing some database modifications today and updating the model, this error appeared. The solution builds with no errors but this error is listed in the Error List. When I run the application I get the error as soon as I try to access the model.

Answer (score 1):

they had the same issue on the msdn forum (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/fa618214-ad3d-42fc-8506-21d539aa2cb3)

check out the answer there, probably some extra stuff in your model which should not be there.  can you post the edmx file?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen to me as well.

The problem turned out to be an association with end-keys, which were not all part of the primary key for that entity!

For instance, deep within my .edmx I had this association:

```
<AssociationSetMapping Name="Table1Table2" TypeName="MyModel.Table1Table2" StoreEntitySet="Table2">
    <EndProperty Name="Table1">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Table1Key" ColumnName="Table1Key" /></EndProperty>
    <EndProperty Name="Table2">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Table2Key" ColumnName="Table2Key" />
        <ScalarProperty Name="Table2OtherColumn" ColumnName="Table2OtherColumn" />
</EndProperty></AssociationSetMapping>
```

and the definition of Table2 looks like this:

```
<EntityType Name="Table2">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="Table2Key" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="Table2Key" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="Table2OtherColumn" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
    ...other properties...
</EntityType>
```

**Notice that `Table2OtherColumn` is in the EndProperty, but is not part of the actual key**.  Removing it from the EndProperty fixed the problem.

Note that **Entity Framework 4** (Visual Studio 2010) **can detect this problem at compile-time**.  Thus, if you are having serious trouble tracking down what table/property is causing this, just load your project into VS 2010 Express (after backing it up!) and try to compile.